# literate for each loop my string in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim txtLinqSum1Ad, txtLinqSum2Ad, txtLinqSum3Ad, txtLinqSum4Ad as String
```

instead of writing this thing

```
   TextBox1.AppendText(txtLinqSum1Ad & vbNewLine)
   TextBox1.AppendText(txtLinqSum2Ad & vbNewLine)
   TextBox1.AppendText(txtLinqSum3Ad & vbNewLine)
   TextBox1.AppendText(txtLinqSum4Ad & vbNewLine)
```

I would like to do something like that

```
For i as integer = 0 to 3

TextBox1.AppendText(txtLinqSum & i & Ad & vbNewLine)

Next
```

Do you think that could be possible? it would be useful when I have a lot of strings?

Comment: Put them into a collection and enumerate them, for example with Dictionary https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2 you can store each string with their own name and retrieve them accordingly

Comment: Given that the only difference between the variable names is a number, I'd think that an array would be the way to go.

Comment: `TextBox1.AppendText(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, {txtLinqSum1Ad, txtLinqSum2Ad, txtLinqSum3Ad, txtLinqSum4Ad}))`. The collection of elements to concatenate in `String.Join()` can be an array or IEnumerable of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with `CallByName()`, or via Reflection (much longer syntax).

For `CallByName()` to work, though, your variables have to be PUBLIC at Form/Class level:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public txtLinqSum1Ad, txtLinqSum2Ad, txtLinqSum3Ad, txtLinqSum4Ad As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        txtLinqSum1Ad = "A"
        txtLinqSum2Ad = "B"
        txtLinqSum3Ad = "C"
        txtLinqSum4Ad = "D"
    End Sub

    Private Sub butBereken_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butBereken.Click
        For i As Integer = 1 To 4
            Dim s As String = CallByName(Me, "txtLinqSum" & i & "Ad", CallType.Get)
            TextBox1.AppendText(s & vbNewLine)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

But just because you can, doesn't mean you should. An array or other type of collection (List/Dictionary) would probably be a better choice.